# Handle new data from a merged Lead

Tags: apex, error-messages, lead-conversion, merge, recycle-bin

I have a process that is sending Lead data out of Salesforce. The system of record is Salesforce. 3 months later, the Lead data sent comes back into Salesforce with updated data.

There is a chance that during those 3 months, out of the 100k+ leads sent, one can be merged because of matching/dupes rules. With merges, a merged lead will either be in the recycling bin or be 100% deleted.

- What is the best way, in Salesforce, to handle update events when the record no longer exist? Via apex trigger and error handling?
- If the lead is in the recycling bin, is there a way to find the "winning lead" id that a lead was merged to?

Comment: Your first question doesn't make a ton of sense to me but the second can be answered with the `MasterRecordId` field. *If this record was deleted as the result of a merge, this field contains the ID of the record that was kept. If this record was deleted for any other reason, or has not been deleted, the value is null.*

Comment: seems like an even bigger problem would be that after 3 months, the lead was converted and hence no longer updateable